# First Website - messing around but the second column moves down when I add margins (not next to the first column) - don't know how to fix

Tags: html, css, css-grid, margin, margin-left

```css
body {
  background-color: #040081;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #1612AA;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto" sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 #F36502, -2px 0 #F36502, 0 2px #F36502, 1px 1px #F36502, -1px -1px #F36502, 1px -1px #F36502, -1px 1px #F36502;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.part1 {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}

.part2 {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
}

.img1 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.row:after {
  display: grid;
  clear: both;
}

.columnLeft {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.columnRight {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #1612AA;
  color: #F36502;
  padding: 20px;
}

.img2 {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fractal Forward</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 class="part1">Fractal Forward</h1>
    <img src="mandelImage.webp" class="part2 img1">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="columnLeft">
      <div class="card">
        <h2>Blog Entry Title</h2>
        <img src="image1.jpeg" class="img2">
        <p>This is the beginning of the blog Yay Yay Ya! The first couple sentences. Eventually I'm going to figure out how to code it so the first three sentences are automatically here and I don't have to type it out...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="columnRight">
      <div class="card">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried adding 'margin-left: 50px;' to the .columnRight class so that there'd be space in-between the two columns, but every time I do that it shifts columnRight underneath columnLeft. Without the margin-left for the column there's no separation between the two columns and it doesn't look very good. Not sure how to fix this, or what I did wrong. This is my first attempt at creating a website and this has been my first real sticking point. Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: So, you have 70% + 30% + 50px which doesn't fit. Which values do you want to adjust and by how much so that they add up to 100%?

Comment: @Alohci oooooohhh yeah that makes sense. If I added margin-left: 50px; to an element within the columnLeft container then it would indent it 50px within the 30%, but because I did it for the columnLeft it's all adding up to over 100%.

I didn't articulate that well (very new, still learning the lingo) but I just changed that and it worked. Thank you! I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working haha 

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS function [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) like this.

```
.columnRight {
  /*other properties*/
  width: calc(30% - 50px);
  /*other properties*/
}
```

Comment: ooooh that's interesting. I'll try that - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 80% + 20% *equals* 100%, so 80% + 20% + 50px is *greater than* 100%.

Instead of specifying column sizes on the elements and using the older `float` layout algorithm, I suggest setting column sizes on the containing element and use CSS’s modern `grid` algorithm to handle the exact implementation details:

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <style>

    .row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 80% 20%;
    }

    .columnLeft,
    .columnRight {
    width: initial;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<!-- ... -->
```

Then you don’t need to use `float`, `clear`, or `::after`. Using the grid algorithm also allows you to add a `gap` property to the row div.